# Interpreting & Analysing a Transitional Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, matrix-equations

[image]

How do you interpret such a problem

Are we expect to add the rows, and that would be the one with larger number of goats in the long term. Therefore A(row 1) and b(row 2)... therefore the answer is A... the exam paper says A, but is this the right way of dealing with this qs? How else could I approach it?

Comment: I think there is some information missing, as your figure does not contain any question. I would expect that the question would be something like "Which location A or B will the goats prefer in the long term". In this case, given a vector $v_{starting}=(goats in A, goats in B)$, you could just apply $lim_{n \to \infty} T^n v_{starting}$. Is this what you are searching for? If not, could be please add additional information.

Comment: is there not an image?

Comment: question asks: assuming the total number of goats remain constant, a transition matrix that would predict this outcome is: and options A,B,C,D

Comment: i need a method that uses a matrix reasoning rather than vectors